# how to make a jQuery click function play a song in jPlayer?

Tags: jquery, click, jplayer

is it possible to create a jQuery click function that will play the first song in a jPlayer playlist?

i've been referring to the documentation here:

http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/

and there is an example of a link that displays 'play' which when clicked plays the first track in a playlist, but i'm not sure how this is being triggered.

the documentation later references:

> **play([index:Number]) : Void**
>
> Plays the item in the playlist. Plays the current item if no param is given. A positive index plays items from the start of the playlist while a negative index plays items from the end.

```
// Examples of usage:
myPlaylist.play(); // Plays the currently selected item
myPlaylist.play(0); // Plays the 1st item
myPlaylist.play(1); // Plays the 2nd item
myPlaylist.play(-1); // Plays the last item
```

so my question is, can this functionality be triggered through a click function in jQuery and if so could anyone advise on the basic syntax that would be required?

thank you.

update:

to provide more context and an example of what i am attempting, in the head area there are existing click functions and i'm trying to add the instruction to play the track here as well, for example:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".open_doors").click(function(){
$("#leftdoor_inner").animate({"left": "-=164px"}, 'slow');
// etc ....
// here is attempt to trigger jPlayer
myPlaylist.play(0); 
});
</script>
```

and this is the playlist defined in the head area:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1",
verticalVolume: "true",
}, [
{
title:"Cro Magnon Man",
mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3",
oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.ogg"
},
{
title:"Your Face",
mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-05-Your_face.mp3",
oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/TSP-05-Your_face.ogg"
}
], {
swfPath: "js",
supplied: "oga, mp3",
wmode: "window"
});
});
//]]>
</script>
```

so this set up is currently not working and i am not sure if i am referencing the playlist properly in the jQuery click function.

thank you.

**update, solution:**

ok i figured out a solution, i had to add the code within the script area that defines the playlist (see above) in the following fashion:

```
{
swfPath: "js",
supplied: "oga, mp3",
wmode: "window"
});
$(".open_doors").click(function() {
myPlaylist.play(0);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems too simple an answer, so forgive me if I'm missing something, but have you tried this sort of thing? (Replace "element" with the appropriate selector for your use case.)

```
$("element").click(function(){
    myPlaylist.play(0);
});
```

Comment: hello, i think it is that simple but i am just not sure of the syntax to use.  i have added my attempts above, thank you.

Comment: for your information, i figured out a solution posted above, thanks again!